# jQuery set value of an element from an object

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I set a value of an element with JQuery from an object $this?

I have some divs of class "A"

```
<div class="A">
  <span name='B'>some text</span>
  <div>
      <input name='value_1' value='15'/>
      <input name='value_2' value='9'/>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="A">
  <span name='B'>some other text</span>
  <div>
      <input name='value_1' value='7'/>
      <input name='value_2' value='12'/>
  </div>
</div>

...more divs like those
```

I'm trying to set the text of the spans of name B with the greater value of their inputs (inputs 'value_1' and 'value_2').

But what I'm trying seems to fail, this is the js (using jquery):

```
function setSpans(){
    var value1=0;
    var value2=0;
    var setting_value = 0;
    $('.A').each(function(){
        value1 = $(this).find("input[name='value_1']").val();
        value2 = $(this).find("input[name='value_2']").val();

        if(value1 > value2)
            setting_value = value1;
        else
            setting_value = value2;

        //here comes what I can't accomplish
        $(this).find("span[name='B']").text(setting_value);

    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is to cast string values to numbers before you compare them:

```
var value1 = Number($(this).find("input[name='value_1']").val());
var value2 = Number($(this).find("input[name='value_2']").val());
```

Remember that value of the input field is always a string and of course **string** `"9"` is greater then `"15"`.

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ck64v16t/

Comment: Then I was right... that jsfiddle works. Unfortunatelly my original code still doesn't work. I'll check it later and report why. Thanks

Comment: Solved, stupid mistake (id instead of name in the template, yes.. I know). BTW, now I'm casting before comparing thanks to you.

Comment: Good, glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 1):

Two problems that I see:

- time of `setSpans` call. It has to be after used elements are already in DOM - either by using `document.ready` or by placing script after these elements in page.
- values of `input`s are Strings, so you can use, for example, `parseInt` to compare values as Numbers.

Workable example:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tks0rwm7/).

HTML:

```
<div class="A">
    <span name='B'>some text</span>
    <div>
        <input name='value_1' value='15'>
        <input name='value_2' value='9'>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="A">
    <span name='B'>some other text</span>
    <div>
        <input name='value_1' value='7'>
        <input name='value_2' value='12'>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(setSpans);

function setSpans()
{
    var value1 = 0;
    var value2 = 0;
    var setting_value = 0;
    $('.A').each(function()
    {
        value1 = parseInt($(this).find("input[name='value_1']").val());
        value2 = parseInt($(this).find("input[name='value_2']").val());
        if (value1 > value2)
        {
            setting_value = value1;
        }
        else
        {
            setting_value = value2;
        }
        $(this).find("span[name='B']").text(setting_value);
    });
}
```